# How to unravel decimal (interpolated) indices in Python?

Tags: python, image, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of indices in an interpolated image which I need to order.
I thought it would work best if I first ravel these indices to get a systematic ordering and then unravel them.

The `np.ravel` worked fine but when unravelling them back, `np.unravel_index` don't allow decimals.

I wonder if there is an existing function somewhere that allows unravelling decimal indices.

Comment: What is your code doing? What is your data set looking like? `unravel_index` is working with indices; they are integers.

Comment: The data is a 2d numpy array image. The code finds positions in the image and therefore it has to describe the x and y of these positions in possibly decimals. These x and y are equivalent to the indices but aren't necessarily integers. They have the data type float by default